# programmatically fire onchange event on polymer input

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

To fire onchange event on html input one can use this line of code:

```
  document.getElementById("test").onchange()
```

Is it possible to do something similar on Polymer input?
This is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
 document.getElementById("gold-zip-input-id").onchange()
 document.getElementById("gold-zip-input-id").inputElement.onchange()
```

Comment: Text input doesn't have change event. Use focus and blur instead.

Comment: Here is a scenario: I have  polymer input onchange event executing some logic. It works when user manually enters data. Now when I populate that input programmatically onchange event is not firing. That means I need to trigger that event. This works on html input: document.getElementById("test").onchange(). Nothing so far works with Polymer. Does that mean that Polymer components functionally more limited than it's plan HTML counterparts?

Answer (score -1):

I have never used polymer, but it looks like you could be after the [behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html) section of the guide.

> A behavior is an object that looks similar to a typical Polymer prototype. A behavior can define lifecycle callbacks, declared properties, default attributes, observers, and listeners.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using paper-input element you can use the change event:

```
<dom-module id="change-test">
    <template>
      <paper-input label="total" type="number" value"{{val}}" on-change="handleChange">
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "change-test",
            handleChange: function (e) {
                console.log("Value changed to " + this.val)
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#event-change